# Split a tf.data.Dataset in to two distincts Input and Target tf.data.Dataset

Tags: tensorflow

How can I create two distincts Input and Target tf.data.Dataset from a tf.data.Dataset containing both Input and Target data so that I can uses them as x and y parameters of the model.fit function?

I use the code below to load the dataset

```
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(
        dataset_file_path, 
        compression_type='GZIP', 
        buffer_size=None, 
        num_parallel_reads=None
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

How did you create this dataset?

If each element in the dataset is in the format `(input_data, target_data)` then you can do

```
input_dataset = dataset.map(lambda x,y: x)
target_dataset = dataset.map(lambda x,y: y)
```

Comment: It works now. It took time for me to make it work because I'm not familiar with TF Records and Tensors.

Comment: Great! You should look at this website --> https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord It is a bit overwhelming but you can learn a lot about dealing with TFRecords.